# Azure Storage Queues - Is there an App wide configuration for setting poison messages TTL

Tags: azure, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I'm using an Azure Webjob which is triggered by Storage Queues, using [QueueTrigger] attributes, and poison message handling is done by the integration package itself.

I'm trying to find a way to set the `ExpirationTime` for poison messages to something greater than the default 7 days.

[Looking at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue), these are all the configuration options available:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
            "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
            "batchSize": 16,
            "maxDequeueCount": 5,
            "newBatchThreshold": 8,
            "messageEncoding": "base64"
        }
    }
}
```

[The options to configure it by code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.host.queuesoptions?view=azure-dotnet), also doesn't seem to help:
[image]

### Question:

Is there a way to configure the queues so that poison messages have a custom `ExpirationTime` ?

Note: I am aware that you could switch to manual way of handling poison messages, and there will be a property on the queue message, however I'd prefer to not fallback to that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no config available to control that. Few options depending on what works best

1. increase the visibility time + dequeuecount to let the message stay longer before it even moves to the poison queue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#host-json
2. Use a different trigger to read the messages from poison queue and add it to a different queue with a longer TTL as required. [Expiration date of poison queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303298/expiration-date-of-poison-queue)
3. Register a custom queue processor that takes over the handling of poison messages and you are free to use different TTLs as required https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/440576/azure-queue-storage-set-ttl-for-the-poison-queue-j.html